# custom jquery mobile problem

Tags: theming, javascript

I added only my custom jquery mobile theme, made .info file, html.tpl.php, page-front.tpl.php, added jquery update module, and everything are loading fine.
But when I want to click to some link, example "#some", nothing happens. I double check all code, but seems that something is overlaping.

You can see that admin toolbar menu is bolded for some reason:

[image: snap]

other effects work fine, but non of links that start with "#" don't work.

Comment: is hard to answer your question without seeing your code

Comment: links with a hash are supposed to be loaded by javascript, is there any error in the javascript console

Comment: Please post your code, bearing in mind that this is a site for questions about Drupal - if your question is completely a javascript one it most likely won't be on-topic here.

Comment: No javascript errors, check example on: http://nightlifecroatia.com/

Comment: There is an err. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ01q.png

Comment: thank you @Nikhil M , I fixed that erros, but everything from question bove stay, for some reason links with "#" doesn't work, maybe some behavoiur or event that drupal has in it's core stoping it.